# Postfix reject on Centos 5.11?

Tags: postfix, centos5

i like to config postfix to reject ALL incoming emails except one that is whitelisted

what i was try:

/etc/postfix/sender_access

```
someone@somwhere.com OK
foo@bar.org REJECT
```

it is working , but i don't know how to make pattern match for ALL address on the end to REJECT all non listed address
like:

```
someone@somwhere.com OK
etc   OK
etc   OK
*@* REJECT
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

solution:

in **/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
#
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
reject
#
```

and the format of **/etc/postfix/sender_access**

```
/^.*someone@somewhere.com$/ OK
/^.*alloweddomain.com$/ OK
```

any other sender will be rejected